# Running Spring Boot Application in Dev Mode causes beans to be duplicated

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-boot-test, spring-boot-testcontainers

I want to run my Spring Boot application in the dev mode:

My main (prod app):

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<MyApp>(args = args, init = {
        addInitializers(BeansInitializer())
    })
}
```

App in the dev mode:

```kotlin
import com.myApp.main as prodMain

object MyApplicationTest {
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        SpringApplication.from(::prodMain)
            .with(RedisContainerDevMode::class.java)
            .run(*args)
    }
}
```

```kotlin
@TestConfiguration
class RedisContainerDevMode {

    @Bean
    @ServiceConnection("redis")
    fun redis(): GenericContainer<*> =GenericContainer("redis:latest").withExposedPorts(6379)

}
```

Apart from this, I have a context initializer that is needed for tests using `@SpringBootTest`

```yaml
context:
  initializer:
    classes: com.myApp.BeansInitializer
```

This initializer causes Bean definitions to be loaded twice and crashes the development app.

How I can simultaneously have:

1. Run tests using `@SpringBootTest` and have beans initialized from `BeansInitializer`
2. Be able to run the app in the dev mode without duplicated beans?

Comment: Are the `BeansInitializer` in your main method and listed under `context.initializer.classes` that same class? If so, it's to be expected that the initializer will be called twice as you've configured things such that that's what will happen.

Comment: I know that this is expected, I look for a way to make it called once for @SpringBootTest and once for application in the dev mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found is to remove the initializer from `application.yml` in tests and move it to the `@SpringBootTest` annotation.

```kotlin
@SpringBootTest(properties = ["context.initializer.classes=com.myApp.BeansInitializer"])
```

This makes a perfect fit for both integration tests and running Testcontainers powered Spring Boot app